# Best way to play/pause/seek large audio files with precision in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, animation, audio, html5-audio

Having read articles like [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785354/web-audio-api-seek-play-buffer-progress) and [this](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs), I'm still unclear on how to play/pause/seek large audio tracks in javascript with time precision.

I'm developing an animation library which allows you to create animation timelines that would control WebGL buffers and DOM elements and pretty much anything else. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I just got to audio tracks, and what it needs is:

1. Ability to play large tracks
2. Play/Pause
3. Seek
4. Time precision
5. It would be a bonus to be able to have audio effects and control their parameters at precise times.

I have used the audio element before to play an animation in sync with the music. I used to update the animation's clock with the audio element's `currentTime` property. I remember that `currentTime` was not very reliable. In Chrome, I used to offset `currentTime` by a large number compared to the precise times I would extracted using Adobe Audition, and in FireFox, I would offset even more — 50ms if I recall correctly. And I did that just to keep thing in sync on my machine, and perhaps most of my visitors. Two years later now, with new version of Chrome and Firefox, it seems I should tweak that `offset` variable to get things in sync again.

Obviously, that's not the best approach.

Now, for my new application, I figured I could get precision with Audio API and just schedule to play tracks on precise times, but then the problem will be how to play large tracks (some 15 minutes long, overlapping), and yet have play/pause/seek for multiple tracks, etc. Memory/perf would also be important.

What approach would fit these needs?

For clarity, the use case is something like Adobe After Effects or Premiere or any other software that comes with a timeline for visual effects with audio in sync.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you cannot do this using the Web Audio API.

According to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer), the `AudioBuffer` object is "designed to hold small audio snippets, typically less than 45s".

For large files, you should use a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`, which takes the audio data from an `<audio>` or `<video>` HTML element. Those elements stream the data from the server, so it does not need to be loaded and decoded upfront, allowing you to use files of any size.

The disadvantage of using a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` is that it does not support many of the basic operations that an `AudioBuffer` supports, like seeking. If I understand correctly, this is not something vendors can fix, as the server would need to implement part of the system.

In practice, Chrome and FireFox (I don't know about any others) will load tracks longer than 45 seconds. I have only tested two songs, but both worked perfectly. One was 2:56 (*Africa Unite* by Bob Marley) and the other was 5:50 (*Method Man* from *36 Chambers*); both were MP3 files. I also tried to load an hour long talk and the page crashed. My laptop can easily hold an hour-long audio buffer in memory, but I think Chrome and Safari limit the memory a page can use, and maybe FireFox too.

Sorry this answer is a bit anecdotal. The Web Audio API implementations are new, so you really just have to try stuff with different engines and see what happens at this stage, and I've only played around with the API myself.

Comment: Thanks! One solution that *may* work (I've yet to try it), is to split the buffer data into smaller chunks and schedule each chunk to play after the previous chunk.